# Haswell 4770k 1866 or 1600 ram difference?

Tags: memory, cpu, intel-core-i7

Hi all i am getting this proccessor and am still not decided on the ram. I was told haswell works best with 1600 and that all 1866 is 1333mhz overcloked to 1866 so its best to get the 1600?

I will be using the intergrated graphics for a while until i can afford a graphics  card. I will also be getting dominator  platinums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/75123/Intel-Core-i7-4770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) says this CPU supports only 1333 MHz and 1600 MHz RAM. Anything faster than 1600 MHz will work, but it will be underclocked to 1600 MHz, so there's no point in buying 1866 MHz RAM.

> I was told haswell works best with 1600 and that all 1866 is 1333mhz overcloked to 1866 so its best to get the 1600?

Let's say you have two cars. First one has 150hp engine and second one has 120hp engine, but it was tuned to 180hp. Which one has more horsepower?

But that doesn't matter anyway, because 1866 MHz RAM would be underclocked to 1600 MHz for the CPU to support it.